# Cebysev (Tschebyscheff-) Approximation

Tags: analysis, approximation, online-resources, approximation-theory

I have to find the best Tschebyscheff-Approximation of $x(t) = \sin(t)$ on the Interval $[0,d]$ by a line where $0 < d < 2\pi$. But I have no idea how to perform such an approximation, do you have any resources where it is explained, I can not find anything good?

Comment: [http://www.goddard.net.nz/files/js/chebyshev/cheby.html](http://www.goddard.net.nz/files/js/chebyshev/cheby.html) will do it for you if given $d$.  Note that you get a very different expression on $[0,d]$ compared with $[-d,d]$

Comment: thx for the link, but I meant the approximation just for a line! not for arbitrary polynomials...

Comment: By "a line" do you mean a linear function like $ax+b$?

Comment: yes, a function of the form $ax + b$.

Comment: @Henry Looks like the script has a bug that manifests itself on polynomials of degree $ 1$. The result I get when approximating $\sin$ on $[0,2\pi]$ is a non-optimal line, and the picture is that of a parabola. (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Posting another answer, because  the other one uses a different approach and has   comments concerning that approach.</sup>

Let's begin with a more general situation:   we want the best uniform (Chebyshev) linear fit to a smooth function   $f$ on an interval $[A,B]$. A variational argument (which is standard, and therefore  omitted) shows that if $ax+b$ is the best fit, there  are three points $x_1<x_2<x_3$ at which the difference $f(x)-(ax+b)$  attains values (left to right) $M,-M,M$, with  $|M|=\max_{[A,B]}|f(x)-(ax+b)|$. Note that $M$ can be negative or positive, we don't know.

Since $x_2$ is an interior extremum of $f(x)-(ax+b)$, we have $a=f'(x_2)$. The other two extrema could be interior or boundary points, we don't know. But we do know that 
$$f(x_1)- f'(x_2) x_1 = f(x_3) - f'(x_2) x_3 \tag1$$
since both sides are equal to $M+b$.

So there are quite a few cases to check in general. For the concrete situation, we know that $f'(x)=\cos x$ cannot attain  same value three times. Therefore either $x_1$ or $x_3$ is an endpoint, maybe both. More specifically, either $$(x_1,x_2,x_3) = (0, z , 2\pi-z) \tag2 $$
or
$$(x_1,x_2,x_3) = ( z , 2\pi-z, d) \tag3 $$
or 
$$(x_1,x_2,x_3) = (0, z , d) \tag4 $$
In each of these three cases, we have one unknown $z\in(0,2\pi)$ which can be found by solving (1).

Then compare the maximal deviation you get from $$2M = (f(x_1)-f'(x_2)x_1) -  (f(x_2)-f'(x_2)x_2)$$ and pick the solution with the smallest $|M|$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $at+b$ be the optimal line. Note that the best $b$ is the average of the maximum and minimum of $\sin t-at$. Thus, it remains to find $a\in\mathbb R$ such that the oscillation of $\sin t-at$ on the interval $[0,d]$ is minimized. (Oscillation is the $\max-\min$ difference).

One can visualize the problem in terms of the graph $G=\{(t,\sin t):t\in [0,d]\}$. The oscillation of $\sin t-at$ is the length of a skew projection of $G$ onto the vertical axis. We want the direction of projection that minimizes this length, "the position of the Sun when $G$ has the smallest shadow."

Unfortunately, the computation is a tedious case-by-case analysis. There are between $2$ and $4$  points $t$ where $\sin t-at$ could attain an extremum:
$$t_1=0, \quad t_2=d, \quad t_3=\arccos a, \quad t_4=2\pi -\arccos a$$
The last two may or may not be in $[0,d]$. So the maximum of $\sin t-at$ is
$$\max(0,\sin d-ad, \sqrt{1-a^2} - at_3, -\sqrt{1-a^4} - at_4)   $$
where some of the last two may have to be excluded. Similarly the minimum. I'd   plot these as functions of $a$ (I assume you have a specific value of $d$) to see what goes on.

Comment: Hi. thank for you answer! But after some researching I found resources where they say to determine the optimal line w.r.t. the uniform norm to a function $f : [x_0,x_1] \to \mathbb R$ we have to solve the four equations: i) $f(x_0) - (ax_0 + b) = \delta$, ii) $f(t) - (at + b) = -\delta$, iii) $f(x_1) - (ax_1 + b) = \delta$ iv) $f'(t) - a = 0$ in the unknowns $a,b,t,d$. Why is this procedure not applying here?

Comment: @Stefan I understand where these equations are coming from, but they appear to be for functions that are either convex or concave. Look at the assumptions on $f$ in the proof.

Comment: No, I do not find anything about such assumptions in the theorems, see http://www2.maths.ox.ac.uk/chebfun/examples/approx/html/OscError.shtml "the best degree n approximation is characterized by the equioscillation of the error at least $n+2$ times"

Comment: @Stefan I see. I suggest that you repost your comments as an answer, and I'll delete mine.

Comment: I am still unsure if this is correct, because for $d = 2\pi$ I get $a = 0, b = 0.5$ as solution (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-b%3Dd%2C+sin%28x%29-%28ax%2Bb%29%3D-d%2C+sin%282pi%29-%282*pi*a%2Bb%29%3Dd%2C+cos%28x%29-a+%3D+0) which could not be right, because this has a bigger difference to $sin(x)$ as for example $f(x) = 0$...

Comment: the long link is not working, so: http://goo.gl/SRxuSy

Comment: also regarding your first comment that $b$ should be the average of the maximum and minimum I am not quite sure about it, cause intuitively I came to the conclusion that between $[0,2\pi]$ the optimal line should look something like that: http://goo.gl/nLjbnT and here the intercept is not $0$ (which would be the average of $1$ and $-1$)..

Comment: @Stefan Please note I referred to maximal deviations of $\sin t -at$, not of $\sin t$ itself...   The best line for $\sin t$ on $[0,2\pi]$, whatever it is, has to pass through the point $(\pi,0)$ by symmetry, and it will have   negative slope. So, the maximal deviations from this line are $d, -d, d, -d$, which breaks the suggested approach based on solving the system of equations.

Comment: @Stefan What I mean is, the system of equations is derived under the assumption of a particular pattern of deviations from the optimal line. This patter holds for concave and convex functions, as well as for some functions that aren't too far from these. For example, on the interval $[0,3\pi/2]$ it will probably work. But not always.

Comment: ah ok, that makes it clearer. I guessed it is enough that the maximal deviations are attained at at least three points, which is also given for $sin$ (here it is even attained at four points), but that does not seems to be enough...

Comment: @Stefan One fix is to try other patterns of signs besides $+,-,+$, and pick one with smallest magnitude of deviation. I think   $+,- ,- $ will work for the sine when the interval is long.

Comment: Can you please explain your reasoning why $b$ equals the average of the minimum and maximum? As I see it if $at+b$ is optimal, then $f(t) := sin(t) - at$ attains it minimum at $t = 0$, where $f(0) = 0$. Now the line "$at$" has a maximum deviation from $sin(t)$, now I can slide "$at$" up or down to minimize this, but by this process I add an intercept $b'$, and exactly when this equals half the maximum it equals the optimal intercept $b$, for otherwise if $b' < b$ then I can still slide upwards to minimize the maximum. So when I am halfway I reached the optimum. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: @Stefan Say, you have the numbers $1,3, 6,10$ and you want to subtract the same number $b$ from all of them to minimize their maximal magnitude. What would you subtract? $(1+10)/2$. Because only $1$ and $10$ really matter.

Comment: ok, that is simple :)